# Using Observables to propagate changes in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have two components, a Parent and a Child:

```
// Parent Directive
@Component({
   selector: 'parent-directive',
   template: `
    <button (click)="nextVal($event)"></button>
    <button (click)="prevVal($event)"></button>
    <child-directive [content]="myValue"></child-directive>`,
   directives: [ChildDirective]
})
export class ParentDirective {
    public myValue : string;

    constructor() {this.myValue = "Hello";}

    nextVal() {this.myValue = "Next";}

    prevVal() {this.myValue = "Prev";}
}
```

This is the child directive:

```
// Child directive
type ObservableContent = Observable<string>;

@Component({
    selector: 'child-directive',
    template: `<div></div>`
})
export class ChildDirective {
    @Input() content : ObservableContent;
    subscription : Subscription;

    constructor() {
        // I instantiate the content property as an observer. I want to see if it logs anything.
        this.content = new Observable<string>(ob => {console.log('constructor', ob)});

        // I'm trying to get the propagated values here.
        this.subscription = this.content.subscribe(value => { console.log('value', value);});
    }
}
```

Let me break down what I'm trying to do here. I have a child component nested in parent component. The parent has two buttons, `next` and `prev`, which when clicked change a property bound to the scope of the parent.

The child has another property, `content` that is bound to the `myValue` scope property of the parent. When I update `myValue` in the parent, I want the `content` property of the the child to change. However when I try to subscribe to that value the subscription listener is never called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

As I can see `content` is a string and not an Observable. So you don't need to use `.subscribe` here as it will throw an error.

In your child component `this.content` will always give you the latest value. Just use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. This makes sure that angular updates the component only if one of its input attributes is changed.

To get the latest value of `content` in component use the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle method provided by angular.

```js
// Child directive
type ObservableContent = Observable<string>;

@Component({
    selector: 'child-directive',
    template: `<div>{{content}}</div>`,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildDirective {
    @Input() content : ObservableContent;

    ngOnChanges(changes) {
     console.log('new content' + changes.content.currentValue);
     console.log('old content' + changes.content.previousValue);
  }
}
```

The content in template will always reflect the updated value due to Angular's change detection.

Comment: I thought we're looking for the way of catching the moment when the value of `content` was changed, but not just output it in a template. For outputting in a template you don't need any `Observable` things.

Comment: I dont need to write the `content` value to a template. I need to capture it as a property of the `Child` component.

Comment: The logs appear once when the component is loaded, but not when the parent value is changed. Please keep in mind im trying to propagate a change from the parent to the child.

Comment: 'When I update myValue in the parent, I want the content property of the the child to change. However when I try to subscribe to that value the subscription listener is never called. What am I doing wrong?'. This is your question and I my answer is for this. Maybe you would like to edit your question so that I can better understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle. Your answer does not work when I use it.